# Verify that the user can do an action

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entites Person and Nursery and a `ManyToMany` association between them.

A user can have the role ROLE_MANAGER and be a manager for several nurseries.

For that in every action on his dashboard I need to verify if he's linked to the nursery if I don't do it he can modify the nursery slug in the url and have access to a nursery that he is not linked with.

Is there a way to check that on every action in the nursery manager dashboard without copy/paste a verification code in every action ?

As I understood Symfony Events (or Voters ?) can do that but I've never used them before ...

**EDIT :** Maybe it's easier to understand with a little bit of code ! 
So my nursery dashboard function is :

```
public function dashboardAction($nursery_slug)
{
    //$currentUser = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $nurseryRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VSCrmBundle:Nursery');

    $nursery = $nurseryRepo->findOneBy(array('slug' => $nursery_slug));

    // Sometimes may help
    if(!$nursery)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("The nursery has not been found or you are not allowed to access it.");
    }

    return $this->render("VSCrmBundle:Manager:dashboard.html.twig", array(
        'nursery' => $nursery
    ));
}
```

To protect this dashboard I need to verify if the current user is linked to the nursery, somethink like :

```
$verification = $nurseryRepo->findOneBy(array('person' => $currentUser));
if(!$verification){throw accessDeniedException();}
```

But at the moment I'm obliged to do this test on every action in the manager dashboard ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to implement to make this work smoothly.

First off, you need a NurseryVoter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Something like:

```
class NurseryVoter extends Voter
{
    const MANAGE = 'manage';

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::MANAGE))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$subject instanceof Nursery) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $nursery, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            // the user must be logged in; if not, deny access
            return false;
        }
        // Check the role and do your query to verify user can manage specific nursery
```

Wire everything up per the link.  And at this point your controller code is reduces to:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('manage', $nursery);
```

Get all that working first.  After that, use a Kernel:Controller event to move the deny access code from the controller to a listener.  Follow the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Your controller listener gets called after the controller is assigned but before the controller action is actually called.  The trick here is how to determine which action actually needs the check to be done.  There are a couple of approaches.  Some folks like to flag the actual controller class perhaps by adding a NurseryManagerInterface.  The listeners check the controller to see if it has the interface.  But I don't really care for that.

I like to add this sort of stuff directly to the route.  So I might have:

```
// routes.yml
manage_nursery:
    path: /manage/{nursery}
    defaults:
        _controller: manage_nursery_action
        _permission: CAN_MANAGE_NURSERY
```

Your listener would then check the permission.

Updated with a few more details on the kernel listener.  Basically you inject the authorization checker and pull _permission from the request object.

```
class KernelListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    // @security.authorization_checker service
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct($authorizationChecker,$nuseryRepository)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->nurseryRepository = $nuseryRepository;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => [['onController']],
        ];
    }
    public function onController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $permission = $request->attributes->get('_permission');
        if ($permission !== 'CAN_MANAGE_NURSERY') {
            return;
        }
        $nursery = $this->nurseryRepository->find($request->attributes->get('nursery');

        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('MANAGE',$nursery) {
            return;
        }
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Some message');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) The first part works perfecttly ! But the second one seems really difficult to me. I've created a new class like : class ControllerListener{ public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) { }} but then I don't understand : should I inject the router and verify if the route contains _permission ? should I call the voter service inside this class and make decisions from that or just paste $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('manage',$nursery); and find $nursery from $event ?

Comment: Added a few more listener details.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Thanks to you I have +10 in symfony experience now :p PS: IF THIS COULD HELP SOMEONE =>  the find method gives you an array of objects so for me I needed findOneBySlug method that return an object. It will not work if your find method return an array

Comment: Glad you got it working.  By convention, find should only return one object.  But whatever works for you.

Comment: Ah ok so this is because in my routes (and controller) I need slug parameter  so it was not working for me with find (nursery). Anyway thanks a lot now I understand better this part of the framework which doesn't have a lot of examples :)